# Removing one word from a string C#

Tags: c#, string

I'm making a little conversation AI, and I'm trying to make it so that it asks the user how they are. Instead of typing loads of different possible answers I'm trying to narrow it down a bit by removing the word "thanks" in the reply so that there are less possibilities. So instead of having to create the responses "good, "good thanks", "great" and "great thanks", if the word thanks is in the reply it will just remove it and will only have to look for "good" or "great"
I got the removing the word part from another website but I don't think I am using it correctly. 
Here is my code so far.

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
    string name;
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Oh hi {0}! Nice to meet you.", name);

    Console.WriteLine("How are you doing today?");
    string mood;
    mood = Console.ReadLine();
    mood = mood.ToLower();
    int index1 = mood.IndexOf("thanks");
    if (index1 != -1)
    {
        string mood2 = mood.Remove(index1);
    }
    else
    {

    }
    if (mood2 == "good" || mood2== "alright" || mood2 == "great")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Good to hear that!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ah well");
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try string.Replace

Comment: if you remove (index1) its removing 1 character - which you omitted to point out - try removing "all" of it although as @Mueui has said there are other choices

Comment: `string mood2 = mood.Replace("thanks", "");`

Comment: Do you actually need to remove the word or just check if any of the words (`mood2 == "good" || mood2== "alright" || mood2 == "great"`) are in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of the `Remove` method is actually correct. According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc(v=vs.110).aspx) it :

> Returns a new string in which all the characters in the current instance, beginning at a specified position and continuing through the last position, have been deleted.

your code should give you a compiler error that the variable `mood2` does not exist in the current context. Either move the declaration out of the if-scope:

```
string mood2 = "";
if (index1 != -1)
{
    mood2 = mood.Remove(index1);
}
```

or simply overwrite the original `mood` variable and use it for further comparison:

```
if (index1 != -1)
{
    mood = mood.Remove(index1);
}
else
{

}
if (mood == "good" || mood == "alright" || mood == "great")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Good to hear that!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ah well");
}
```

a much easier way of checking would be to use the [String.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) method. It will check whether you string contains a specific word. So you can skip the removing part an simply check like this:

```
string mood = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

if (mood.Contains("good") || mood.Contains("alright") || mood.Contains("great"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Good to hear that!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ah well");
}
```

EDIT:

If you want to check for negation you can do it the same way:

```
if (mood.Contains("good") || mood.Contains("alright") || mood.Contains("great"))
{
    if(mood.Contains("not")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ah well");
    }
    else
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Good to hear that!");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ah well");
}
```

the same you need to do for the bad descriptions of the mood like "bad", "terrible", "horrible" ect.

Comment: I hope you don't mind I added your top part in my answer (I gave credit of course)

Comment: @EpicKip that's entirely fine :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I've tried your second method with String.Contain and it works great. However, as EpicKip stated, it doesn't work for false positives like if I were to say "Not good" as the code is just looking for the word "good". Would I be able to use this same method to look for the word not and if the string is a positive word plus the word "not" it returns "Ah well" and vice versa for a negative word with the word "not"?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a word like you did before but the string wasn't initialized (as [Mong Zhu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46361999/2885376) said) so you need to initialize it and then it will work:

```
string mood2 = "";// < Correct if this is added
if (index1 != -1)
{
    mood2 = mood.Remove(index1);
}
```

---

**Cleaner method:**

But do you actually need to remove the "thanks" part because as it stand you only check what else is in that string (`mood2 == "good" || mood2== "alright" || mood2 == "great"`) You could just check if your string contains one of those words, the code would become a lot shorter:

```
string[] moods = { "good", "alright", "great" };
string name, chosenMood;

Console.WriteLine( "What's your name?" );
name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine( "How are you doing today?" );
chosenMood = Console.ReadLine();

if( moods.Any(mood => chosenMood.ToLower().Contains(mood)) )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "Good to hear that!" );
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine( "Ah well" );
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

This way you can also type something like 'Pretty darn good!' and it will still work.

*It will give false positives if you answer something like 'Not good at all :('*

Answer (score 0):

For your goal, I would just check that user's `mood` starts with your "feeling good" words.

```
var goodAnswers = new string[] {"good", "alright", "great"};
if (goodAnswers.Any(okAnswer => mood.ToLower().StartsWith(okAnswer)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Good to hear that!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ah well");
}
```